# Speex-encoded SWF?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash, speex

[A project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154643/in-flex-dynamically-load-sound-object-from-encoded-bytes) that I'm working on requires being able to dynamically create sound-asset SWF files (using DefineSound tags).  Even though I've been able to successfully create DefineSound tags using raw pcm, I haven't been able to do so with Speex.

The [SWF format spec](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf) (pgs 202-204) specifies that you can use Speex in a DefineSound tag, but its fairly vague about the specifics.  Is it just the output of `speex_bits_write` with no framing?  Is it the same as the output of speexenc (e.g., an Ogg file)?  Is it a series of frames with a [length before each one](http://speex.org/docs/manual/speex-manual/node13.html)?  I've tried variations of all these and none of them work.

CS4 can be used to create sound-asset SWFs, which is useful for having a real-world example.  The problem is, the GUI only allows for some encodings (MP3, Nellymoser, raw, etc), but not Speex.

So, my question is: has anyone done this?  Can you point me to a reference implementation or an example Speex SWF?

Comment: It looks like between this post and your last linked above that you've already gotten deeper into the roots than I've been so pure speculation here but this link may help? http://askmeflash.com/article/1/all-about-speex-for-flash

Comment: Can you create an FLV file that is only audio and use Speex audio codec when creating FLV?

Comment: Yes, its possible to create a speex-encoded FLV.  (You can do it with the Xuggler ffmpeg build.)  The problem I'm having is creating a speex-encoded *SWF*.